# Create a mask in Simulink with edit field as enumeration

Tags: matlab, simulink, mask, enumeration

I want to create a mask on a subsystem, like the mask of the Enumerated Constant (shown below). As you see in the blue circle, the Value can be edited using a drop down list of possibilities. The Enumerated Constant

[image: Mask of Enumerated Constant]

If creating a mask it is indeed possible to make a Popup instead of an Edit but the problem with this is that the list of possible selections needs to be manually created inside the mask. What I want is that this Edit value only shows the possible selections of a certain enumeration that I want to specify only ones. The Enumerated Constant mask does this with an Edit type but even then it works.

Of course I tried to reverse engineer this from this block but I can not find how Matlab does this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my initial question was quite clear if I read it now. The enumerals should be taken from an enumerated type from a Data Dictionary. So based on the answers of Julian and DrBuck I could answer my own question.

I first get the enumerated type from the data dictionary.

```
% set name of DD and type
DDName = 'types.sldd';
EventType = 'Dem_EventIdType';
% Get DD entry
myDictionaryObj = Simulink.data.dictionary.open(DDName);
dDataSectObj = getSection(myDictionaryObj,'Design Data');
entryObj = getEntry(dDataSectObj,EventType,'DataSource',DDName);
entryValue = getValue(entryObj);
```

Then I get the enumerals and add the event type to it. This will be used to fill the pop-up options.

```
% Get enumerals
NoOfEvents = length(entryValue.Enumerals);
for i = 1:NoOfEvents
    EventIDs{i,1} = [EventType '.' entryValue.Enumerals(i).Name];
end
```

After this I used the above proposed code to manipulate the created pop-up menu with the enumerals from the Data Dictionary.

```
maskObj= Simulink.Mask.get(gcb);
par_name = 'Value_eventID'; % name
par_idx  = find(strcmp({maskObj.Parameters.Name},par_name)); % index of parameter
maskObj.Parameters(par_idx).TypeOptions = EventIDs; % enum options
```

I do this not in the 'Initialization Commands' but in the callback function of the 'Refresh events' button. When the block is added from the library it only contains the INVALID_EVENT. After a refresh it does a fresh look-up and adds the current enumerals to the list.

My end result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite figure out how to do this but hopefully this answer should get you on the right track.

Create two popups on the mask, eg 'popup1' and 'popup2'. Hardcode your type options to popup1, and leave popup2 blank and disabled (because it's dependent on what you select with popup1). You can then use a callback on popup1 to populate popup2 when the first one is clicked. Your callback would look something like this:

```
% Grab the value selected from popup1
value = get_param(gcb, 'popup_1');

% Do some sort of check/switch statement to set your options
if value == 1 
    % Enable popup2
    set_param(gcb, 'MaskEnables', {'on', 'on'});
    % Set the type options for popup2
    set_param(gcb, 'MaskStyleString', 'popup(1|2|3|4|5),popup(my|new|options)');
end if
```

Have a look at [this](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/control-masks-programmatically.html) and [this](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/create-dynamic-mask-dialog-boxes.html) in the Matlab/Simulink documentation. `get_param` and `set_param` are useful if a bit unintuitive. It looks like in later versions of Simulink you can use `maskObj = Simulink.Mask.create(gcb);` methods to do this sort of stuff, which might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

as DrBuck sugessted, you should use `maskObj = Simulink.Mask.create(gcb)` to create a mask for the currently selected block (gcb) or select an already existing mask by `maskObj=Simulink.Mask.get(gcb)`. Then, add parameters to it:

```
par_name   = 'foo'; % name
par_prompt = 'This is my enum constant'; %prompt
maskObj.addParameter('Prompt',par_prompt,'Name',par_name); % add parameter
```

The field you are looking for is called `TypeOptions`, but first you must find the correct parameter number by e.g.

```
par_idx  = find(strcmp({maskObj.Parameters.Name},par_name)); % index of parameter
```

Set the mask parameter to 'popup' and create your enum values:

```
maskObj.Parameters(par_idx).Type = 'popup'; % type
maskObj.Parameters(par_idx).TypeOptions = {'Option1','Option2'}; % enum options
```

There you are ;)

HTH Julian